# Combine two columns under one header in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two Numpy arrays which I need to combine maintaining only certain columns from `A` - size `(888, 1114253)`, depending on the rows I have in `B` - size `(555861, 3)`.

The problem is that the header of `A` is `55730`: each column has two values!

In other words I want to get only the columns of `A` where the header corresponds to the rows in `B`, but in `A` each column is "double"

An example will clarify:

`A`:

```
family id mum dad  rs1  rs2  rs3  rs4  rs5  rs6  rs7  rs8  rs9  rs10  rs11  rs12
     1  1   4   6   A T  A A  T T  C C  G G  A T  A G  A A  G A  T A  G G  C C 
     2  2   7   9   T A  G A  C T  C T  G A  T T  A A  A C  G G  T A  C C  C T 
     3  3   2   8   T T  G G  C T  C T  G G  A T  A G  A C  G G  T T  C C  C C 
     4  4   5   1   A A  A A  T T  C C  G A  T T  A A  A A  G A  T A  G C  C T
```

Since in this file each `rsxxx` column header has two corresponding columns, I have to find a way to put them together, so I can read the file as an array

`B`:

```
1  rs1 2345
1  rs2 2346
2  rs5 2348
4  rs8 2351
4 rs12 2360
```

The desired output is

`Output`:

```
 family id mum dad  rs1 rs2 rs5 rs8 rs12
  1      1   4   6  A T A A G G A A C C
  2      2   7   9  T A G A G A A C C T
  3      3   2   8  T T G G G G A C C C
  4      4   5   1  A A A A G A A A C T
```

Ideas?

On the console

`B`:

```
array([['1', 'rs3094315', '752566'],
       ['1', 'rs12562034', '768448'],
       ['1', 'rs3934834', '1005806'],
       ..., 
       ['23', 'rs2032612', '21866491'],
       ['23', 'rs2032621', '21872738'],
       ['23', 'rs2032617', '21896261']], 
      dtype='<S10')
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how your data look like in numpy (output in the console)? Because now we only see plain text.

Comment: Now I showed how the "B" file looks... actually I can't even read the "A" because the number of columns is different in the first compared to the other rows...

Comment: to read A you can use np.loadtxt(A_txt,skiprows=1), or create another A_txt with the proper number of columns in the first line. I still did not get what you want to do with B

Comment: I explained better what I want to do in the question. As for skiprows, I can't because I need those names to analyze the file; rather than creating the right number of cols in the first line I would want to "group" each couple of "A G" in one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each column is separated by two spaces, but that each gene pair is separated by one space.  If this is so you can use

```py
delimiter='  '   #two spaces
```

in `np.loadtxt`:

```py
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO # for example file

a = StringIO("""family  id  mum  dad  rs1  rs2  rs3  rs4  rs5  rs6  rs7  rs8  rs9  rs10  rs11  rs12
1  1   4   6   A T  A A  T T  C C  G G  A T  A G  A A  G A  T A  G G  C C 
2  2   7   9   T A  G A  C T  C T  G A  T T  A A  A C  G G  T A  C C  C T 
3  3   2   8   T T  G G  C T  C T  G G  A T  A G  A C  G G  T T  C C  C C 
4  4   5   1   A A  A A  T T  C C  G A  T T  A A  A A  G A  T A  G C  C T """)


nrs = 12        # number of `rs` columns, for dtype
dt = 'int,'*4 + 'S10,'*nrs

A = np.genfromtxt(a, delimiter='  ', names=True, dtype=dt)
```

`A`:

```py
array([ (1, 1, 4, 6, ' A T', 'A A', 'T T', 'C C', 'G G', 'A T', 'A G', 'A A', 'G A', 'T A', 'G G', 'C C'),
       (2, 2, 7, 9, ' T A', 'G A', 'C T', 'C T', 'G A', 'T T', 'A A', 'A C', 'G G', 'T A', 'C C', 'C T'),
       (3, 3, 2, 8, ' T T', 'G G', 'C T', 'C T', 'G G', 'A T', 'A G', 'A C', 'G G', 'T T', 'C C', 'C C'),
       (4, 4, 5, 1, ' A A', 'A A', 'T T', 'C C', 'G A', 'T T', 'A A', 'A A', 'G A', 'T A', 'G C', 'C T')], 
      dtype=[('family', '<i8'), ('id', '<i8'), ('mum', '<i8'), ('dad', '<i8'), ('rs1', 'S10'), ('rs2', 'S10'), ('rs3', 'S10'), ('rs4', 'S10'), ('rs5', 'S10'), ('rs6', 'S10'), ('rs7', 'S10'), ('rs8', 'S10'), ('rs9', 'S10'), ('rs10', 'S10'), ('rs11', 'S10'), ('rs12', 'S10')])
```

Then to access only the columns from `B`, do something like this:

```py
b = StringIO("""1  rs1 2345
1  rs2 2346
2  rs5 2348
4  rs8 2351
4 rs12 2360""")

B = np.genfromtxt(b, usecols=[1], dtype='S10')
```

Now, use `A[B]`:

```py
A[B]
array([(' A T', 'A A', 'G G', 'A A', 'C C'),
       (' T A', 'G A', 'G A', 'A C', 'C T'),
       (' T T', 'G G', 'G G', 'A C', 'C C'),
       (' A A', 'A A', 'G A', 'A A', 'C T')], 
      dtype=[('rs1', 'S10'), ('rs2', 'S10'), ('rs5', 'S10'), ('rs8', 'S10'), ('rs12', 'S10')])
```

Or, if you want the first four columns too:

```py
A[['family', 'id', 'mum', 'dad'] + list(B)]
array([(1, 1, 4, 6, ' A T', 'A A', 'G G', 'A A', 'C C'),
       (2, 2, 7, 9, ' T A', 'G A', 'G A', 'A C', 'C T'),
       (3, 3, 2, 8, ' T T', 'G G', 'G G', 'A C', 'C C'),
       (4, 4, 5, 1, ' A A', 'A A', 'G A', 'A A', 'C T')], 
      dtype=[('family', '<i8'), ('id', '<i8'), ('mum', '<i8'), ('dad', '<i8'), ('rs1', 'S10'), ('rs2', 'S10'), ('rs5', 'S10'), ('rs8', 'S10'), ('rs12', 'S10')])
```

Comment: Awesome! Anyhows, each column is separated by one tab and not two spaces - but I couldn't type the "tab" in the question.. how can you write the tab character in the question?? Anyways, I tried delimiter="   " #tab and it works as well!

Comment: It's taking forever (I have a 2G file and my laptop is a Mac OS X, 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) - is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: If the `rs` numbers are sequential, you could load only those those columns using the `usecols=[1,2,5,8,12]` or `usecols=4+B` for example.  If only a few of the `rs` are used compared to the size of the file, this will help reduce the size of the loaded array, but I'm not sure how much faster it will be.