# Numpy: order array as other array - by string order

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I need to sort array A columns according to one column of array B, but the order is given by strings: I want the array A columns to be ordered like the second column of array B (`B[:,1]`)

array A

```
family  id  mum dad     rs1     rs2     rs3     rs4     rs5     rs6     rs7      rs8     rs9     rs10   rs11    rs12

     1   1   4    6     A T     A A     T T     C C     G G     A T     A G      A A     G A     T A     G G     C C 

     2   2   7    9     T A     G A     C T     C T     G A     T T     A A      A C     G G     T A     C C     C T

     3   3   2    8     T T     G G     C T     C T     G G     A T     A G      A C     G G     T T     C C     C C

     4   4   5    1     A A     A A     T T     C C     G A     T T     A A      A A     G A     T A     G C     C T
```

array B

```
1   rs1    2345
1   rs5    2346
2   rs6    2348
4   rs8    2351
4   rs12   2360
3   rs2    2456
2   rs3    2453
3   rs10   5672
1   rs9    78923
5   rs7    5738
2   rs4    3546
6   rs11   6354
```

Desired output:

```
family  id  mum dad  rs1     rs5     rs6     rs8     rs12    rs2     rs3     rs10    rs9     rs7     rs4     rs11
   1    1   4     6  A T     G G     A T     A A     C C     A A     T T     T A     G A     A G     C C     G G
   2    2   7     9  T A     G A     T T     A C     C T     G A     C T     T A     G G     A A     C T     C C
   3    3   2     8  T T     G G     A T     A C     C C     G G     C T     T T     G G     A G     C T     C C
   4    4   5     1  A A     G A     T T     A A     C T     A A     T T     T A     G A     A A     C C     G C
```

I hope this is clear enough! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate (by same user): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693122/combine-two-columns-under-one-header-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, this is essentially a duplicate of this question:
[Combine two columns under one header in Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693122/combine-two-columns-under-one-header-in-numpy-array)

So this answer is essentially cut and paste from there, only I'm using tabs for delimiters since I understand that is what you are using.

First we start off with the A array using StringIO to generate the sample data.

```
import numpy
from StringIO import StringIO

a = StringIO("""family\tid\tmum\tdad\trs1\trs2\trs3\trs4\trs5\trs6\trs7\trs8\trs9\trs10\trs11\trs12
1\t1\t4\t6\tA T\tA A\tT T\tC C\tG G\tA T\tA G\tA A\tG A\tT A\tG G\tC C 
2\t2\t7\t9\tT A\tG A\tC T\tC T\tG A\tT T\tA A\tA C\tG G\tT A\tC C\tC T 
3\t3\t2\t8\tT T\tG G\tC T\tC T\tG G\tA T\tA G\tA C\tG G\tT T\tC C\tC C 
4\t4\t5\t1\tA A\tA A\tT T\tC C\tG A\tT T\tA A\tA A\tG A\tT A\tG C\tC T""")

dt = 'int,int,int,int,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3,S3'
A = numpy.genfromtxt(a, delimiter='\t', names=True, dtype=dt)
```

Then we get column 1 from the B array, same as the previous question:

```
b = StringIO("""1\trs1\t2345
1\trs5\t2346
2\trs6\t2348
4\trs8\t2351
4\trs12\t2360
3\trs2\t2456
2\trs3\t2453
3\trs10\t5672
1\trs9\t78923
5\trs7\t5738
2\trs4\t3546
6\trs11\t6354""")

B = numpy.genfromtxt(b, usecols=[1], dtype='S10')
```

At this point, as was explained in the previous questions, you can get the `rs` columns ordered by `B`, using `A[B]`. Or if you want all the columns:

```
A[['family','id','mum','dad']+list(B)]
```

If you want that printed out as something more closely representing your example output (tab separated columns), you could just do something like this:

```
cols = ['family','id','mum','dad']+list(B)
result = A[cols]

for line in [cols]+list(result):
  print '\t'.join([str(col) for col in line])
```

I don't have much experience with numpy, so there may be easier ways to format your output with numpy directly, but that's at least one possible solution.

Comment: My huge problem is that I have to extract the "list(B)" from a 2G file and it's taking DAYS - I can't split the file because I need to extract the "B" values searching on the entire file and all the solutions I've found tell to split the file or the array. I couldn't find a way to do so with pytables either, which seems to be faster. Are there any solutions for this? Thank you.